# How to conditionally select previous row's value in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to select the previous row's value only if it meets a certain condition
E.g.

```
df:
Value  Marker  
10  0  
12  0  
50  1  
42  1  
52  0  
23  1
```

I want to select the previous row's value where `marker == 0`if the current value `marker == 1`.

Result:

```
df:
Value  Marker  Prev_Value  
10  0  nan
12  0  nan
50  1  12
42  1  12
52  0  nan
23  1  52
```

I tried:
`df[prev_value] = np.where(df[marker] == 1, df[Value].shift(), np.nan)`
but that does not take conditional previous value like i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
df['Prev_Value']=np.where(dataframe['Marker'].diff()==1,dataframe['Value'].shift(1, axis = 0),np.nan)
```

Output:

```
df

   Value  Marker  Prev_Value
0     10       0   NaN
1     12       0   NaN
2     50       1  12.0
3     42       1   NaN
4     52       0   NaN
5     23       1  52.0
```

If you want to get the previous non-1 marker value, if `marker==1`, you could try this:

```
prevro=[]
for i in reversed(df.index):

    if df.iloc[i,1]==1:
        prevro_zero=df.iloc[0:i,0][df.iloc[0:i,1].eq(0)].tolist()
        if len(prevro_zero)>0:
            prevro.append(prevro_zero[len(prevro_zero)-1])
        else:
            prevro.append(np.nan)
    else:
        prevro.append(np.nan)
        
df['Prev_Value']=list(reversed(prevro))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Value  Marker  Prev_Value
0     10       0         NaN
1     12       0         NaN
2     50       1        12.0
3     42       1        12.0
4     52       0         NaN
5     23       1        52.0
```

Comment: nope thats not what I want. I want the previous value as shown in result df.

Comment: so in case of index[3], I would want the next previous value with ```marker == 0```, which is 12 (index[1]), instead of nan.

Comment: I don't get it. The condition isn't that  *previous row's value where `marker == 0`  if the current value `marker == 1`*?. At index[3] you current marker  value is 1 and previous row's marker value is 1, not 0.

Comment: so the thing is when I have 1 in my current row, i want to lookup the previous non-1 value and return that as previous value. Is it clearer?

Comment: Yeah, that's cleaner. Just edited my answer to that condition, checkout it. And as a suggestion, try to be more clear with the conditions, because *previous row's value where marker == 0 if the current value marker == 1* means to check the the immediate previous row, which is different to check the previous non-1 rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216442/discussion-between-sam92-and-mrnobody33).

Answer (score 2):

```
condition = (df.Marker.shift() == 0) & (df.Marker == 1)
df['Prev_Value'] = np.where(condition, df.Value.shift(), np.nan)
```

Output:

```
df
   Value  Marker  Prev_Value
0     10       0         NaN
1     12       0         NaN
2     50       1        12.0
3     42       1         NaN
4     52       0         NaN
5     23       1        52.0
```